# jQuery on click exclude a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to disable clicks on certain elements within a parent div with jQuery. How can it be done?

My approach was to try to exclude it from selection:

```js
$('.wrap1 :not(.wrap3 li)').on("click", function() {
  alert(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap3">
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be clickable</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result that I'm looking for is: if I click inside the `wrap1` div, it should prompt me the alert box, except when I click inside the `wrap3` div.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is checking the event's target.

```
$('.wrap1').on("click", function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).is(".wrap3, .wrap3 *")){
    alert(1);
  }
})
```

```js
$('.wrap1').on("click", function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).is(".wrap3, .wrap3 *")){
    alert(1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap3">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
    ABC
    <div style="background-color:dodgerblue;">
    CDE
    </div>
    </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be clickable</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the whole `wrap3` div, not just the `<li>` element?

Comment: @Radical_Activity I've updated my answer. Try it out!

Answer (score 1):

there is no need of `function` keyword in arrow function

```js
$('.wrap1 :not(.wrap3 li)').on("click", e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap3">
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be clickable</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still prompting me the alert when I click on the <li>

Comment: I was not knowing that it was what you wanted but I'm done

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your way doesn't work, but this does:

```js
$('.wrap1 li').not('.wrap3 li').on("click", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap3">
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be clickable</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's strange is that it's only giving me the alert when I click the list 1,2,3 texts, but not getting one when I click on `some-text` or to the empty area next to the list. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`

[jQuery Stop Propagation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/event-stoppropagation.htm#:%7E:text=Description%3A,(on%20that%20event%20object).)

```
<script>
    
$('.wrap1').on("click", function(){
  alert(1);
});

$(".wrap3").on("click", function(event){
  // This will stop propagation of the event to parent element.
  event.stopPropagation(); 
});
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```js
$('.wrap1').on("click", function(e) {
  if( $(e.target).is('.wrap3 li') ) { return false; }
  alert(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap3">
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be clickable</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```